# node-red - custom node - Dynamically update HTML form when event

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I am currently working with node-red and I created some custom nodes.

Now, I want to update dynamically the node parameter form: I want to retrieve a list containing data label from a server and put them into a select so the user can choose what data he wants to get.

[image: The HTML form I want to update dynamically]

Here, for instance, I would like to get the data contained in the container from broker. So what I want to do is to add a new select input when the container and the broker are filled.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

I already took a look into the custom edit behaviour (http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/properties) but there are only events when the form is validated/cancelled/opened/... there are not events on the inputs themselves.

Thank you for the help :)

Gabi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how several Node-RED nodes work. You need to use the `oneditprepare` function in the node's HTML file to call a HTTP endpoint hosted by your node.

You can also attach `onchange` type hooks to fields in the form to update later fields based on earlier input using AJAX style calls.

There are plenty of examples in the [node-red-nodes](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes) git repository, have a look at things like the [serial port node](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/tree/master/io/serialport) for example that looks up a list of available ports that can be configured.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will add a button and on the oneditprepare I will configure the onClick event and do the queries I need to display the complementary inputs. Also, is there any way to access the broker inside the oneditprepare?

Comment: Hi, so I've done what you suggested, i.e: I put event handlers and I updated the DOM. But no way to access the broker. Thank you again.

Comment: You connect to the broker from the server side and use http to pull that info into the UI

Comment: Is there an example that uses `onchange`? Searching the `node-red-nodes` report brings up nothing.